# Lifecycle Callbacks don't work in my new project with Symfony 2.3.6

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-2.3

I am not new with Symfony, I work in multiple project from 2.0 to 2.3 and i use lifecycle callbacks several times successfully.

Now I install latest Symfony 2.3.6 like:

```
php composer.phar create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition path/ 2.3.6
```

I Always use Annotations anywhere.

I add good annotations in top of my entity like this:

```
<?php

namespace Myproject\AdminBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="category")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Category
{
```

and **PrePersist** annotation:

```
/**
* @ORM\PrePersist
*/
public function addTitleSuffix() 
{
    $this->title = $this->title . '--test';
}
```

I make several test in writing

```
@ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
```

or with

```
@ORM\PrePersist()
```

or add exit in `PrePersist` and not work :(

My entity good persist to my mysql db but not enter in my `prepersist` method.

My controler was generated with crud.

My insert method is:

```
/**
 * Creates a new Category entity.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="category_create")
 * @Method("POST")
 * @Template()
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Category();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('category_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

From my composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "~1.1",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "dev-master"
}
```

I have updated today.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i generate automatic my entities like:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AcmeBlogBundle yml
```

it's generate yml and yml has precedence over annotations on entity.

When i delete yml all works fine

Answer (score 0):

if you use YMAL (metadate) you didn`t need to write annotation

```
@ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
```

on the top of your Entity class 
 and write  annotation

```
@ORM\PrePersist
```

on top of your method which you need to execute pre persist

**JUST** write  name of your method in YMAL file lik this:

```
lifecycleCallbacks:
    prePersist: [addTitleSuffix]
```

like in [Documentation Of Symfony 2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html)